# Jenkins' String parameter vs Text parameter

Tags: jenkins

In a parameterized Jenkins job, what is the difference between `String Parameter` and `Text Parameter`? I don't even see a mention of Text Parameter in the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Text parameter was added in Jenkins, but it didn't exist in Hudson (at least in the past)

Main difference is that the Text parameter supports multi-line, while the String one doesn't

**Update**

Here is the original ticket that requested this functionality
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5577

It doesn't look like something that was *designed* for Jenkins. Rather someone asked for it, and then someone said they have an implementation available. Kohsuke added it to main Jenkins, but from what I've read, it's quite buggy.

Comment: Do you know if there is documentation for it? I am curious to know the other smaller differences as well

Comment: Doubt you would find it. I've updated my answer. If you read the comments on that jira ticket, you will see that this was really an afterthought, rather than a feature.

Comment: Has anyone been using it lately? I'm wondering if it's stabilized. @Slav

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck sorry, I've got no updates for you

Comment: String was able to support multi line in the stored values by e.g. splitting with a line break: '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Using string parameter can deliver full string value, while multi-line string parameter not if your string value is too long.
Jenkins ver. 2.73.1.